# Definition of complex differentiable

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, derivatives

I wonder why the definition of complex differentiable at $z$ is

$f(z+h)-f(z)=f'(z)h+o(|h|)$

instead of

$f(z+h)-f(z)=f'(z)h+o(h)$

It seems the same... But in real analysis, it usually drops the absolute.

Is there any special reason for doing this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It should be $f'(z)\cdot h$. -- Check the definition of $o(f(h))$, the absolute value is part of it.

Answer (score 2):

**Definition:** $f$ is holomorphic at $z_0$ if there exists $\xi_{z_0} \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(z) = f(z_0) + \xi_{z_0}(z-z_0) + o(|z-z_0|)$. One writes $\xi_{z_0} := f'(z_0)$.

The module is needed otherwise it doesn't really make any sense depending on your definition of $f(x) = o(g(x))$. Remember $\mathbb{C}$ can be thought like $\mathbb{R}^2$, so you're really doing multivariable calculus here.

Comment: If $g$ tends to zero, after multiplying $g$ with a unit complex $\frac{|\Delta z|}{\Delta z}$ it still tends to zero, and vice versa. Is that right?

Comment: @gžd15 If $g$ is a function that tends to $0$ as $z \rightarrow z_0$, then $ag$ tends to $0$ as $z \rightarrow z_0$ given any constant complex number $a$ indeed; what's your point?

Comment: Then for the remainder $g(z)=o(|z-z_0|)$, isn't it equivalent to say that $g(z)=o(z-z_0)$?

Comment: It does not really matter. We usually put the module to put emphasis on the objects we're working on, but you're fine writing $o(z-z_0)$ if you prefer, as long as you realize it doesn't really matter ;)

Comment: Understood. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 2):

It is a matter of taste and definitions. In a Banach space $X$ if $g$ is defined in a neighborhood of $x\in X$, I am used to saying that $g(x+h) = g(x) + o(h)$  iff
 $$ \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{\|g(x+h)-g(x)\|_X}{\|h\|_X} = 0 $$
Using that definition you don't need the abs value in the case of the complex plane ${\Bbb C}$. A more precise notation is 
  $$ g(x+h)=g(x)+o_x(h)$$
making precise that the remainder actually depends upon $x$.
Personally I don't see any advantage of putting an abs sign (or norm) inside the "o".